# Converting non-JSON text string into JSON object

Tags: json

I have this simple string repeated 1000's of times for worldwide weather widget I'm using in a large text file:

City Name = "Albuquerque, NM, US" Location = "NAM|US|NM|ALBUQUERQUE" Country = "United States"

Notice how it's formatted.

CITY NAME
LOCATION
COUNTRY

The string I'm actually passing into the Widget is the LOCATION string: "NAM|US|NM|ALBUQUERQUE"

So what I'm trying to do is convert the first example of the CITY NAME, LOCATION and COUNTRY into a JSON OBJECT.

Then, once I have that, I wish to allow the user to INPUT their current location or any location for that matter thereby passing the user input into this:

```
$('#digiclock').jdigiclock({
        // Configuration goes here
        clockImagesPath: "images/clock/",
        weatherImagesPath: "images/weather/",
        am_pm: false,
        weatherLocationCode: "NAM|US|TN|CHATTANOOGA",
        weatherMetric: "F",
        weatherUpdate: "5",
        proxyType: "php"


    });
```

The weatherLocationCode is actually the LOCATION in the string above. So when the user inputs their CITY/STATE or just CITY, I want to parse the newly formed JSON object from the above text, capture the location, and stick-it up in the function.

This is what the end result should be:

```
// JSON OBJECT
{data : [
        {
          "City Name" : "Aachen, DE",
          "Location" : "EUR|DE|GM011|AACHEN",
          "Country" : "Germany"
        }
    ]
}
```

Simple? Not so much.

Comment: It seems that you have multiple doubts. What you already have done to parse your data and turn it into JSON?

Comment: This is where you'd use the technique known as "programming".

Comment: You know, Hot Licks, I really don't need asinine comments from people like you. At 52, I don't have time for games, dumb comments or people implying I'm incompetent. I've been programming longer than you've been alive more than likely. Now, can we dispense with the comments from the peanut gallery and get down to solving the problem.  Just because my question seems like "programming" is the answer, perhaps it's best stated like this: When the student is ready the teacher will appear and when the teacher is ready the student will appear. Perhaps, I'm seeking a teacher and perhaps you're not it.

Comment: Bottom line, what I have a LARGE TEXT file that has each line of code like this:  City Name = "Albuquerque, NM, US" Location = "NAM|US|NM|ALBUQUERQUE" Country = "United States" - Now pay attention hot licks... this is where we do something called: ANALYSIS.  Now what I want to do is convert this 1000 line document into JSON Object vice a TEXT file. Following??? There's going to be a quiz on Friday... Next, let me state, that when the user enters a location code: Say, TN or MA, <-- THESE ARE STATES in the USA... for those that don't know. So once they enter that code, I'll put into the function